# IE 11 Error: This page can't be displayed. Where as it works fine on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed a service which can be accessed by http/https protocol locally.
The address is http://127.0.0.1:8081/

1. When I open it any browser (IE or Chrome), both display it correctly
   (No issue)
2. When I click login:
3. Chrome redirects it to https://127.0.0.1/login/ then it shows
   security error which I bypass and after that it works fine.
4. IE 11 redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8081/login/ then displays 'This
   page can't be displayed'.

My work arround:

I reset all settings.

I removed/deleted history, cookies etc.

I also tried google a lot but no luck.

What I think:

I think the issue is with IE setting or something, because the site is running well in Chrome as it should run. So there might not be any IIS issue.

What is your opinion?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: IE will redirect to "http" url or "https" url? If it is "https" url, the problem might be the self signed cert. I think you can try install the cert to your IE browser and test again if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks @xwhyLikeThis for your comment. But this is not certificate issue or might be (bit confused at this point) if there is certificate issue, IE generally displays warning message from there you can continue or cancel.but it not displaying that message.Also the service is self signed, no certificate to install.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem.
I think there might be a number of reason for this issue.
But I just want to put the way which I figure out to fix the problem which might help someone.

The issue was with IP Address.

- The PC IP was: **10.0.0.121**
- And sub net was: **255.255.255.0**

I changed the sub net to: **255.0.0.0** and issue resolved.

Thanks

Happy Coding :)